# Converging matrix and its form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm studying converging matrices now and following case is important for me.

How to  prove statement (if it is always true) that for any matrix $A_{n\times{n}}$ of **rank $n$** where  entries in any its row are **non-negative** and give always **sum = $1$** (property *), we have with $n\to\infty$ $A^n$  converging 
to rank 1 matrix $B$ of the form

$B=\begin{bmatrix}
       & b_1v  &b_2v   & b_3v  & ... &b_nv 
  \end{bmatrix}$

where    $b_1,b_2,..b_n$ are scalars and     $$\sum_{i=1}^n {b_i} = 1$$     and vector      $ v=\begin{bmatrix}
         1 \\
1  \\ 1 \\...  \\1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}_{n\times{1}}   $ .

Example:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    0.5  &    0.2      &    0  &   0.3     &      0 \\
    0.1   &   0.2    &   0.3     &  0  &   0.4 \\
    0.2   &   0.2    &   0.3  &    0.1  &       0.2 \\
    0.3    &      0   &    0.3       &    0  &   0.4 \\
    0.2   &   0.6    &       0   &       0  &   0.2  \\
        \end{bmatrix}  $

converges to

$B= \begin{bmatrix}
    0.26   &  0.27  &  0.16  &  0.09    & 0.22   \\
    0.26   &  0.27  &  0.16  & 0.09  &   0.22  \\
    0.26   &  0.27   & 0.16 &  0.09   &  0.22  \\
    0.26   &  0.27   & 0.16   & 0.09     & 0.22  \\
    0.26   &  0.27 &  0.16  &  0.09     & 0.22  \\
        \end{bmatrix} $

and

$  0.26 +  0.27 +  0.16  +  0.09    + 0.22= 1$.

If the statement above is true I hope that the dual statement about matrix with columns with property (*) is also true.

If $A$ additionally is symmetrical (we can change column and rows) convergence matrix $B $ has a special simple form.

$B= \dfrac{1}{n}\begin{bmatrix}
    1  &  1 &  ..  &  1    & 1   \\
    1  &  1  &  ..  & 1  &   1 \\
   .. & ..  &.. & ..  &  .. \\
   1   &  1  & ..   & 1    & 1  \\
   1  &  1 &  .. &  1    & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}_{n\times{n}} $

Maybe does also simpler proof exist for this easier case ?

Comment: If you're a bit more precise with your statement, one method of proof is via the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), though more specific, tailored proofs exist.

Comment: It's true under very mild assumptions (just look up Perron-Frobenius theorem on the web), but not true in general. Counterexample: $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$. The sequence $\{A^n\}$ does not converge. It has period 2.

Comment: One proof is given in section 4.3 [of this text](http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/).  See also theorem 8.6 of Billingsley's *Probability & Measure*.

Comment: @User1551 But if all entries <1  but >= 0  is there also counterexample?

Comment: @Widawensis yes, take
$$
A = \frac 12
\pmatrix{
1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1
}
$$
Here, $A^n = A$ for all $n$, so $A$ does not converge to a rank $1$ matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have noticed that counterexamples above have all even dimensions. Has it a meaning?

Comment: These entries **are** less than $1$, see the $\frac 12$ in front.   And the even dimensional examples are easiest to construct, but I could have taken
$$
A = \pmatrix{
1/2&1/2\\
1/2&1/2\\
&&1/3&1/3&1/3\\
&&1/3&1/3&1/3\\
&&1/3&1/3&1/3
}
$$
with the same result.  Similarly, user1551 could have taken
$$
\pmatrix{
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&1
}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Your example BTW is not a good example because I had written in question that matrix rank is n so it should have a rank 4.

Comment: As for rows vs. columns, note that
$$
(A^n)^T = (A^T)^n
$$
where $T$ denotes the transpose.

Comment: @Widawensis missed that.  Still, we could take
$$
A = \frac 13 \pmatrix{ 2&1&0&0\\1&2&0&0\\ 0&0&2&1\\0&0&1&2 }
$$
the computation is a bit less straightforward, but the limiting matrix is still of rank 2 instead of rank 1.  In particular, we find that
$$
A^n \to \frac 12 \pmatrix{ 1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1 }
$$

Comment: ok,  it gives me simple form B for symmetrical matrix A.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom 
Hmm, this is a really counterexample. From what property arises this rank = 2 ? Could we find counterexample with odd rank of A and entries < 1 ?

Comment: Yes, we could.  Have you looked at any of the links in my earlier comments?

Comment: The first link is hard to apply for his case, I don't see direct way.

Comment: @OmnomnomnomThe second also is too complicated for me. Maybe in answer could be more straightforward form of the proof ?

Comment: It's a hard statement to prove, so there isn't a quick proof I can give you.  It would help, however, if you were very specific about *what you want to prove*.  As you can see, the statement you originally intended to prove was false.  However, we can add certain additional assumptions.  Do you want to assume that all entries are strictly positive?  Would you rather assume that the matrix is irreducible and aperiodic?  If you have some other additional conditions that might be helpful to add, let me know, and maybe the statement could be nicely provable.

Comment: I think, however you want to go about proving this, you'll either need to know something about Markov chains, or something about matrix theory for non-negative matrices.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I need such matrices for transforming closed curves. We can assume : **entries are <1 and >= 0** and   all rows are different - there is no the same row in the matrix. ... Additionally (although I was hoping that a case is more general) we can assume that any two colums  in A are **not orthogonal** (this excludes given here counterexamples)

Comment: Generally I would be happy if this theorem would be true for as wide extent as possible so I 'm searching for conditions not too much narrowing its application.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom In preconditions we can also include not orthogonality of rows. It's interesting to notice that if in A there are orthogonal columns (rows) also in converged matrix B are orthogonal. Maybe it could be used even a weaker precondition - not orthogonality of any two **neighboring** columns (rows). The first and last column (row) is also regarded as neighboring.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  I have added some context in a new question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826976/converging-savings?lq=1, maybe it will help in our proof.